# java postgresql using trigger

Tags: java, postgresql

```
SQL = "create view CSaccept as select sID, cName from Apply where major = 'CS' and decision = 'Y' ";
stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

SQL = "create or replace function test1() returns trigger as $$\n" +
                    "begin\n" +
                    " update Apply set cName = New.cName where (sID = Old.sID and cName = Old.cName and Apply.major = 'CS' and Apply.decision = 'Y');\n" +
                    " return Old;\n" +
                    "end;\n" +
                    "$$\n" +
                    "language 'plpgsql';\n" +
                    "create trigger CSacceptUpdate\n" +
                    "instead of update of cName on CSaccept\n" +
                    "for each row\n" +

                    "execute procedure test1();";

 stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

Hi I am writing a program in java using postgresql, and the error like below keeps popping up in the above SQL statement. What is the problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSTEAD OF triggers cannot have column lists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:258)
    at SqlTest2.main(SqlTest2.java:270)
```

```
SQL = "create or replace function test2() returns trigger as $$\n" +
                    "begin\n" +
                    " delete from Apply where sID = old.sID and cName = old.cName and major = 'CS' and decision = 'Y';\n" +
                    " return Old;\n" +
                    "end;\n" +
                    "$$\n" +
                    "language 'plpgsql';\n" +
                    "create trigger CSacceptDelete\n" +
                    "instead of delete on CSaccept\n" +
                    "for each row\n" +
                    "execute procedure test2();";
```

above one works well. I don't know why First one is not working.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You need to remove the `on csaccept` part in the trigger definition. But why an instead trigger to begin with?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What I mean  is I can't understand "ERROR: INSTEAD OF triggers cannot have column lists"

Comment: It means you can't define an instead of trigger that is limited to changes on one (or more) specific column. so you need to remove the column list from the trigger definition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What is the columns lists in my code?

Comment: Your error is in the `SQL` string. It contains invalid SQL. Your problem has nothing to do with java - in case you thought that maybe it did. Maybe you should refer to the PostgreSQL documentation to see how to write the SQL that creates a [instead of] trigger?

Comment: The `on CSaccept` as I have already stated in my first comment.

Comment: I find that sqlite and postgresql differ when they use SQL trigger so can you give me any reference?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "for"
  Position: 59
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , when i delete on CSaccept above error occurs